# Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I am struggling to push my code to Heroku. And after searching on Google and Stack Overflow questions, I have not been able to find the solution. Here is What I get when I try "git push heroku master" :

```
Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.3
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:300:in `open_uri_or_path': bad response Not Found 404 (http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/mail-2.2.6.001.gemspec.rz) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:172:in `fetch_path'
.
....
```

And finally:

```
FAILED: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't think it's a Rails version problem, nor is it specific to Heroku. (I hit the same problem today, when running `bundle install` on my local development machine, with Rails 3.0.3.)

Running `bundle update` locally, as Andrew suggested, fixes the issue.

***Edit***:
As suggested in the comments: remember to `git add .`, `git commit -m "message"`

Answer (score 66):

I have same issue: `remote: ! Failed to install gems via Bundler.`

if you see the problem is this:

```
remote:  Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-16"] but your local platform
remote:  is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle  loc
remote:  --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
```

its mean this :

```
Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-16"] but your local platform is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle loc --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
```

If you see in your gemfile.loc you only have this :

```
PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-16
```

So I did this command, To add in your platform in gemfile.loc

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

This will update your Gemfile.loc :

```
PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-16
  x86_64-linux
```

Continue :

```
git add .
git commit -m "add platform x86_64-linux"
```

Push again

```
git push heroku master:main
```

Solve!

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I've just moved over to an M1 MacBook Air for Rails development and this resolved my Heroku push issues.

Comment: This solved it for me. Perhaps it should be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 20):

I solved this issue this way:

1. bundle update
2. git add Gemfile.lock
3. git commit -m 'Update Gemfile.lock for Heroku'
4. git push heroku master

Answer (score 15):

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
bundle install
git add .
git commit -m "Bundler fix"
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer and welcome to SO! You can add consecutive lines of code by putting them in a code block (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow). It's also generally considered good practice to include some explanatory text about what the code in your answer is doing and how it addresses the question.

Comment: This looks like the cleaner solution, since setting force_ruby_platform 
 config will stay for all projects, which may not be what you want. 
Also, setting both ruby and linux platform seem to be necessary for Heroku deploys ( check this issue: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4269#issuecomment-759591430 )

Answer (score 6):

Another tip:
Open your Gemfile.lock and check if this block exists:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-20
```

If it exists, run the following command:
`bundle config force_ruby_platform true`

Now, you must recreate the whole Gemfile.lock, because some gems can be builded just for MacOS. So, just remove the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` (do no forget to stop spring, if it's running, otherwise spring automatically recreates the Gemfile.lock file)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/ .bundle/ Gemfile.lock
```

I had `Gemfile.lock` at my localserver
make sure to delete it from the localserver AND also the HEROKU V-machine.

Answer (score 3):

1. bundle update
2. git add Gemfile.lock
3. git commit -m 'Update Gemfile.lock for Heroku'
4. git push heroku master

it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Run: bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux

1. bundle update
2. git add Gemfile.lock
3. git commit -m 'Update Gemfile.lock for Heroku'
4. git push heroku master

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Heroku only supports certain versions of Rails, so you need to be on at least 3.0, instead of a release candidate. Update the version of Rails in your gemfile, run `bundle update`, and then try to push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same - 404:

```
curl -v -I http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/mail-2.2.6.001.gemspec.rz
```

In your Gemfile you could try specifying a lower version number of this gem? 2.2.5 perhaps?

Comment: I think it is on the Heroku side, because my Gemfile is extremely simple: gem 'rails', '3.0.0.rc'
  gem 'twitter_oauth'
  gem 'json' gem 'pg'

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using an old pre-release version of Rails? Why don't you see if specifying 3.0.3 works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it by simply pushing it up a second time after letting things sit for a few minutes...  I have re-spun my dokku system from scratch and encountered the same issue, on the same day after I had previously attempted a workaround of updating nokogiri.  That was when I realized, this seems to be an oddity of herokuish; it doesn't always take on the first push.

I wonder if behind the scenes it's installing library headers, and when they take too long, bundler simply fails the install.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was about pg gem.

After installing postgres with 'brew install postgres' bundling finished.

Then doing commands Dyo Medio described, I managed to deploy the app on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this very issue today by purging the cache with steps (and was told it has to be done with each deployment until the bug is found and squashed):
First install the plugin:

```
  heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
```

Then use the following command to clear the cache:

```
  heroku builds:cache:purge -a example-app
```

The cache will be rebuilt on the next deploy. If you do not have any new code to deploy, you can push an empty commit.

```
  $ git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
  $ git push heroku master
```

Where example-app is replaced by the name of the app you want to clear the cache for.