# Heroku push failing due to New Relic RPM gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I've got `gem 'newrelic_rpm'` in my Gemfile as per Heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#addon_installation). When I attempt to run `git push heroku master` I receive the following:

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find newrelic_rpm-3.5.6.46 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:reponame.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've already tried `bundle update` as per this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576816/337903 to no avail.

Comment: Any further information come out of `heroku logs`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**EDIT: 3.5.8.72 of the gem has been released @thanks Chris**

It appears the Bundler Dependency API is having issues.

newrelic_rpm-3.5.6.46 was yanked on January 22, 2013.  But is still being requested by the API.

Locking your gemfile to the current release will fix the issue in the meantime.

```
    gem "newrelic_rpm", "~> 3.5.5.38"
```

Comment: FYI, Version 3.5.8.72 of the gem has been released, and the bundler dependency issues are no more. So a `bundle update newrelic_rpm` will now do the trick.

Comment: You should post this as an answer chris

Answer (score 0):

As chrislopresto mentioned, you may need to do a

```
bundle update newrelic_rpm
```

I'm posting this as an answer since it was suggested, and hey, versions change.